# Why Snapshot and Release repositories for Nexus?

Tags: crud, nexus

When we create repositories for Nexus, we have both snapshot and release repo's created considering that snapshot is for non-releases and release is for release purpose but why do we do this. Why can't we just have snapshot/releases repo to be used for everything. What are the best standards while creating repo's !!

Also, I have gone through the nexus documentation but couldn't find much of best practices. what would be best practices for administering nexus for creating repo's, users and CRUD etc.

Thanks, Appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

This question is broad, but I'll give it a try:

- You can use one Snapshot and one Release repository for the artifacts you create yourself. Furthermore, I would have one (Release) repository for artifacts you upload manually.
- You can proxy as many external repositories as you like (e.g. MavenCentral, Apache etc.).
- It is often a good idea to define groups for you repositories, so that your users can access all relevant repositories as a single entity.
- For accounts: I have one admin account, one account for deployment (that is only used by the build server) and anonymous reading access for everybody in the company. This very depends on whether your Nexus is visible from the internet.